# Saving Dragged Dropped items position on postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sql, ajax, user-interface

Ok I saw many posts on how to serialize the value of dragged items to get hash and they tell how to save them. Now the question is how do I persist the dragged items the next time when user log's in using the has value that I got
eg:

```
  <ul class="list">
        <li id="id_1">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="id_2">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="id_3">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="id_4">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

which on serialize will give

```
"id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=4"
```

Now think that I saved it to Sql server database in a single field called SortOrder.
 **Now how do I get the items to these order again ?**
the code to make these sort is below, without which people didn't know which library I had used to sort and serialize

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".list li").css("cursor", "move");
        $(".list").sortable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options.  One option is to do the sorting server-side.  You would read out that string in .NET to generate the list, in order, on the fly.  Then output it to the browser.

Another option would be output the serialized string as a string variable in javascript.  You could then use jQuery to reorder the elements.  The problem with this method is that there would probably be a flash where the unordered list would display and then the correctly ordered list would appear.

Comment: yes , the second method would be my ideal option. As i can't go on adding server controls into the list from server side each time page is refreshed. Do you any workarounds for the flash [ like a modal display etc ]

Comment: Set the `<ul>` to `display:none` in your CSS file.  Then, after the jQuery runs to sort the list, set `display:block`.

Comment: Simple tip but indeed helps. But this just puzzled me, how do i say take the 3rd li under UL tag then make it first child.Is take a copy ,delete the node then add that copy as child of UL an good practice